# Modify distance of tableFooterView to both last cell of tableView and tableView's margins

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I currently have a `tableView`. In its ViewController, within `viewDidLoad`, I do the following:

```
public override function viewDidLoad() {
    let footerView = bundler.loadNibNamed("FooterView")
    tableView.tableFooterView = footerView
    tableView.tableFooterView.preservesSuperViewLayoutMargins = true
    tableView.tableFooterView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black


}
```

Question 1:
How can I manage to increase the distance of the `tableFooterView` to the last cell? Changing the `layoutMargin` of my cells did the job. Changing the `footerView.layoutMargin` has not had any effect and the distance to the last cell is very minimal.

Question 2:

Neither `footerView.preservesSuperViewLayoutMargins = true` nor setting the `layoutMargins` have an effect and my footerView expands all the way to both right and left margins of the tableView. How can I make the `footerView` respect the tableView's margins?

## Edit - complete code:

This is the important part of the `FooterView.xib` file:

```
<view contentMode="scaleToFill" id="W6V-Yi-de6"  customModuleProvider="target">
        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="431" height="32"/>
        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
        <subviews>
                <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="left" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="tJT-kB-OPd">
                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="355" height="32"/>
                <state key="normal" title="bla bla bla">
                <color key="titleColor" white="0.66666666669999997" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                </state>
                <connections> …  </connections>
                 </button>
        </subviews>
 …
 </view
```

This is the final code:

```
public override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    let footerView = FooterView.loadNibNamed("FooterView")
    footerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: 40.0)
    let frame = footerView.frame

    tableView.tableFooterView = footerView

    let backgroundView = UIView()
    backgroundView.backgroundColor = .green

    let containerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: frame.width - 20, height: frame.height - 10))
    containerView.backgroundColor = .red
    backgroundView.addSubview(containerView)

    footerView.backgroundView = backgroundView
}
```

This is the resulting image:

[image: footerView]

Does anyone know hot to center the `footerView` (basically the text `bla bla bla`) in the middle of the red `containerView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a container `View` inside `FooterView` that has the desired margins from `cell/tableView`. See the below example,

```
class MyFooter: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    let tableViewFrame = tableView.frame    
    let footer = MyFooter()
    footer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableViewFrame.width, height: 150)
    tableView.tableFooterView = footer

    let frame = footer.frame
    let backgroundView = UIView()
    backgroundView.backgroundColor = .green


    let containerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 8, y: 8, width: frame.width - 16, height: frame.height - 16))
    containerView.backgroundColor = .red
    backgroundView.addSubview(containerView)

    footer.backgroundView = backgroundView
}
```

Below is the output

[image]

You can change the `containerView` `x, y, width and height` to adjust the margins.

**Few Notes**

**1)** `viewDidLoad` is not a good place to set constraints. Better to use the above method.

**2)** Changing FooterView's backgroundColor is deprecated so better not to change it .

```
tableView.tableFooterView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
```

Comment: `footer` is a descendant of `UIView` for me, which does not have a `backgroundView`, hence your solution does not really work for me. What class did you use for your `footer` that has a `backgroundView`?

Comment: You just have to inherit your footer from `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`. `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` is descendant of `UIView`

Comment: Thank you. That worked. I did in `viewDidLoad` because all the configuration for the footerView was previously already there. Why is this a bad a idea? Would you mind to explain further why?

Comment: sorry to bother you, but I can't manage to center my `footerView` inside the `containerView`. The containerView and the backgroundView look just like your pic, but the `footerView` shows up inside the red rectangle on the top side. I have tried adjusting its frame, but it does not work. Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try setting the frame in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method. Also if you can share the actual code of setting the footer frames and the design of the footer you are trying to achieve can help provide an exact solution.

Comment: I started doing the changes in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` after it did not worked the first time. The code has been added, don't doubt to ask me if I forgot to add something. Thank you very much for taking a look.

Comment: @regina_fallangi Update this line for the fix. `let containerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: frame.width - 20, height: frame.height - 20))`.  I changed `height: frame.height - 10` to `height: frame.height - 20`. Because you are setting Y to 10, it means this will add padding to top but if you want to add same padding at the bottom you have to set height deducting double than this value i.e 10. I hope you get the point.