# How to display custom footer view in table?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tablefooterview

I have created a `UIview` class `Xib` to display it in footer view of my table.[image: FooterView]

```
import UIKit

/// This class is to display footer view in a settings table view
class FooterView: UIView {
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }
}
```

I'm displaying it as below:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let view = FooterView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: 140))
    return view
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 100
}
```

What's wrong with this? I'm not able to see the footer view and getting so much space between the `tableview` rows.

[image]

Comment: Show us the code of `FooterView` class.

Comment: inherit the [UITableViewHeaderFooterView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewheaderfooterview) when create your custom footer view. And init it with [dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614975-dequeuereusableheaderfootervieww)

Comment: @NiravD I have not done any coding in Footerview class.. It's just xib. Class is inherited from UIView. Have added code in question.

Comment: @QuocNguyen UITableViewHeaderFooterView not allowing to set class name in xib.

Comment: @KrutikaSonawala, why you need to use xib let me know that for tableview, are you use viewController?

Comment: @NikunjKumbhani Yes, I'm using a ViewController.

Comment: @KrutikaSonawala Please check my answer.

Comment: You need a footer view for each section?

Comment: I think the answer to this question may give you a hint on how to add the footer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50927391/modify-distance-of-tablefooterview-to-both-last-cell-of-tableview-and-tableview

Comment: @Mannopson no.. just at the end of a tableview

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Using StoryBoard**

In `UITableView` You can drag `UIView`, it will set as FooterView if you have more then 0 prototype cell. After Drag you can see it in tableview hierarchy as subview. Now, you can add `UILabel` `UIButton` or any component on that View, adjust the height, etc. You can also set `IBAction` into ViewController Class File.

**Programmatically**

```
let customView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 50))
customView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 50))
button.setTitle("Submit", for: .normal)
customView.addSubview(button)

//Add that view in Table Footer View.
tableView.tableFooterView = customView // Here you can also use your xib View.
```

**By using XIB**

```
class MyClass: UIView {

    class func instanceFromNib() -> UIView {
        return UINib(nibName: "nib file name", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
    }
}
```

Initialise the view and use it like below

```
let FooterView = MyClass.instanceFromNib()
tableView.tableFooterView = FooterView
```

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: wow! thank you so much! I have not used instanceFromNib. Is it necessary? is there any other way?

Comment: @KrutikaSonawala Most welcome :) yes it's necessary when you use the xib same like as identifier.

Answer (score 2):

Explanation why your have empty spacing: it is caused by your `heightForFooterInSection` method that leaves 100 pixels for footerView. Unfortunately you haven't register the Nib of the FooterView for your tableView and it does not know what to retrieve in this place.

How to solve your issue:
In your `ViewController` you need to register the Nib of the FooterView to be used by your `tableView`.

E.G.: (Note you need to set `reuseIdentifier` in for your footerView.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.register("FooterView", forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "FooterView")
}
```

After this you can dequeue the footerView in a similar fashion as a cell:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let footerView = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "FooterView")
    return footerView
}
```

Comment: section footers are totally different from table footers

Answer (score -1):

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

     let myFooter =  Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ReportFooterCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! ReportFooterCell

    myFooter.toWorkHours?.text = toWorkHour.toString()
    myFooter.workedHours?.text = workedHour.toString()

     return myFooter
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 40
}
```